# How to map multiple Apache localhost URLs to directories on Windows?

Tags: apache-2.2

I have installed Apache and in httpd.conf have set the DocumentRoot to "c:\testweb" which is available via "`http://localhost`".

How can I now enable it so that "`http://localhost/web2`" goes to "c:\web2"?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
Alias /myapp "C:\web2"
<Directory "C:\web2" >
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride none
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

An example for a settings could be found at:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html 
http://www.nodans.com/index.cfm/2006/10/10/Apache-Directory-Aliases-and-Virtual-Directories 
and in short you should add something like that to the httpd.conf:

```
Alias /web2 c:/web2
<Directory /web2>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

All this assumes that you enabled mod_alias of apache.

Comment: when I add this block to my httpd.conf and restart, it says: Invalid command "Order", what do I need to install so that it understands this command?

Comment: Well it should be inside a specific block of the server inside a "VirtualHost" block in most cases.
If you can share your http.conf it would help.